# iron:router returning route path twice?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm accessing iron:router in a helper which builds breadcrumbs, but oddly I'm getting two objects returned when I do this:

```
console.log(typeof Router.current().route.path(this));
```

I get back:

```
object
string
```

The object is `null` btw...

Does anyone know why? I think it has something to do with reactivity but I don't know where to look to begin.

Comment: I tried this on my project, and it worked just fine. I get string, and if I take out `typeof` I get the path. I don't get an object at all.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it might have something to do with how I call the breadcrumb template. The call is happening twice for some odd reason, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the answer for this, but easiest breadcrumbs are `Iron.Location.get().path.split("/")`

Comment: Thanks, this does return a more useful object including query and hash.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, this tutorial covers a lot about **iron:router**: http://kukuruku.co/hub/javascript/meteor-how-to-build-a-todo-list